# Make outbound call using Plivo sub account

Tags: android, plivo

I am trying use Plivo android SDK to make outbound call. I am following android project sample from plivo documentation (https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/android/plivo-outbound/) and tried to make outbound call using endpoint username and password. It was successful, but right now i want to implement that using my sub account.

Can anyone give me explanation how to make outbound call using Plivo sub account, Is it possible? Because apparently Plivo android SDK doen't provide method to perform outbound call using sub account. That just use endpoint username and password.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

To make outbound calls from a sub account, you should attach the Plivo application (linked to your endpoint) to a sub account. To view the debug logs of a call made from a particular sub account, you should select the sub account name from the drop down [here](https://manage.plivo.com/logs/debug/?type=all) and hit on the "Search" button. If you're still facing issues, please write to support@plivo.com and we can help you resolve this.

Comment: Yes, already attach that. But when I check call logs from the dashboard it was inbound, not outbound. So, what does it means?

Comment: All calls made using SIP endpoint will have an inbound leg (SIP to Plivo) and an outbound leg (Plivo to destination number). If you don't have an outbound leg, it could mean that your Plivo application did not return a valid XML. Please make sure that the answer URL configured in your Application is valid. If you're using the default Direct-Dial app, please make sure that you've added a valid caller ID in the answer URL - http://plivodirectdial.herokuapp.com/response/sip/route/?DialMusic=real&CLID=PLEASE_PUT_CALLER_ID_HERE
If the isse persists, please write to support@plivo.com .

Comment: Hi, I also guess that's the problem. But I still don't know how plivo app configuration looks like because i just frontend dev and still don't have access to dashboard. Btw, thanks for your answer.